# No Python 3.8 installation was detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, installation

[Python installation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W36h4.png)

1.i Uninstall everything of python with advance uninstaller . ( register file and ...)
2.i download the last version of Python from python.org
3. i add the Include PATH file when start the installation of Python.

BUT I don't KNOW WHY ITS NOT Installed !

Comment: There are many things that could go wrong, If you are not up for troubleshooting, I would suggest going for anaconda distributions of Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Error Code 0x80070643**

**I found it.**

if you are not administrator of the system , and change the location of installation , for example (c:\python) this error will be appear .
so you must be install python on (c:\users\'your username'\App Data\Local\Programs\Python)

and after installation python go to system environment and add the path into this.

Answer (score 13):

Delete Python3 Folder--> `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\python`

`Control Panel`--> Uninstall a Program

Right Click on Python and then `Change`--->`Modify`

Click on `Repair` Python.

and then:

`Control Panel` --> `Uninstall` a Program

Now -->`uninstall Python`

Note: To avoid problems, it is better  Delete path Python in `edit environment variables windows`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 :
First install windows x86-64 executable installer and open it.
Then click on repair and done.

If this occurs while uninstallation :
Do the above steps and then uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally copied the python folder from the installed location into my C drive and encountered this problem. Following steps worked for me.

1. Run the Python installer (.exe) file
2. Select the repair option, let it process.
3. Run the Installer again. This time select uninstall and let it process
4. Run the Installer again and this time go with the customization option and check the
   *Add path* option also.

open cmd and type python --version, if it displayed python version. You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10.
Had this issue from a while and after a lot of hit & trials, finally resolved it.
Downloaded the Windows troubleshooter.
Removed every application option with Python's name as suffix, and tried uninstalling from Control panel.
It worked. And then I installed the required python version with ease.
Troubleshooter : **MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab**

Link to download : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

Answer (score 0):

Choose custom installation then next .. your problem will get solve it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following @sjDev answer, I did something similar:

1. Download the installer again
2. Repair
3. Control panel uninstall.

Solved for me. Yeah!