# How to fix (No python 3.8 installation was detected) while installing python for the third time?

Tags: python

This is what it is showing after running the installation file and later opting Install now option

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437756/no-python-3-8-installation-was-detected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Python 3.8 installation was detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437756/no-python-3-8-installation-was-detected)

Comment: @rkdupr0n Please read about [flagging](https://$SITEURL$/help/privileges/flag-posts). It will actually make it easier for you to report duplicates

Comment: I had read that answer but it didn't help me out